# Searching SharePoint Results using Metadata

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

May I ask about how to do the Search for Metadata?

Currently, I'm using this URL, but the result is not the result I need.

**My Metadata column name is MetaTags**

```
/_layouts/15/srchrss.aspx?k=**MetaTags:Bot**%20ListId:9CF05E04-45BC-4EF1-9ED8-B75A71A9010F
```

I try for another method, still the error

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test%20Document%20List%2001')/Items?%20$select=Title,ID,Status&$filter=MetaTags+eq+%27Bot%27
```

**Error:** The field 'MetaTags' of type 'TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti' cannot be used in the query filter expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so long from test and research, I found the answer as below.

```
https://mvponduty.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test%20Document%20List%2001')/Items?$select=Title,FileLeafRef,EncodedAbsUrl&$filter=TaxCatchAll/Term%20eq%20%27Bot%27
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your column does not have a corresponding managed property or your site has not been crawled yet.

Please refer to [this](https://sharegate.com/blog/understand-sharepoint-crawled-and-managed-properties-for-search) article.